# What's the best way to copy objects between .NET applications on the same machine?

Tags: .net, ipc

I have two instances of the same .NET (C#) application running on the same computer. I need to pass some relatively complex objects from one instance to the other. What's the best way to do this.

For background, the instances are our Office AddIn and if both Word and Excel are running, they each create a distinct instance of the AddIn. There's no way to get them to use the same instance.

It is a one-off pass the data from instance A to instance B. And I did think of a named pipe but I believe that would be a royal PITA to serialize and deserialize all the objects - they're complex.

Comment: To clarify, you're asking about a one-off *by-value* copy (i.e. serialization+deserialization)? You're not interested in things like reference-passing, DCOM, .NET Remoting, etc?

Comment: Simplest might be to create a systemwide shared named-pipe and just feed it from `JsonConvert`.

Comment: @Dai - I updated my question to answer your comments. thanks

Comment: There are several .NET process interop mechanisms.  It all depends on how easy it is to serialize the object, but programmers tend to favor WCF for "complex objects".

Comment: @HansPassant I'd argue strongly against WCF, not least because it's effectively EOL'd. WCF is a heavy framework that builds on-top of different IPC methods (`net.tcp`, HTTP, etc) and it doesn't solve the serialization problem because you need to define new `[DataContract]` DTO classes or annotate everything with `[DataMember]` or `ISerializable`.

Comment: Yikes, all that effort to get it ported to .NETCore, updating it as recently as 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step would be to determine if the object you're trying to share can be serialized.

**Best Case Scenario**

If it and all it's descendant properties are POCO/Structs, then this shouldn't be a problem. First reference Newtonsoft.Json, then use the below code.

Since the serializer and deserializer are both going to be Newtonsoft.Json, we can use the type name handling and preserve reference handling options to allow for more complicated types to be serialized.

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{

    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented, // Can remove if you won't read output.
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple, // Don't force specific version of assembly.
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize, // Serialize reference loops, PreserveReferencesHandling will prevent infinite loop.
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All, // Use $ref and $id for looped references.
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All // Include type name of objects when serializing.
    };
}

var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(obj, serializerSettings);
```

Assuming the type being serialized and all it's property descendants have parameterless constructors and the properties don't do anything strange, this shouldn't have any problems.

Test this and if it works, you can possibly remove PreserveReferencesHandling, TypeNameHandling and ReferenceLoopHandling options; however serialization may fail if the object has reference loops or contains any properties where a reference property contains an object of an inheriting type rather than the properties defined type.

Assuming serialization is successful, you can use your preferred method of IPC and just transmit the JSON and deserialize on the other end.

For a memory mapped file, you can use this guide http://www.codingvision.net/tips-and-tricks/c-send-data-between-processes-w-memory-mapped-file

In that example, instead of using the BinaryFormatter, use the example of NewtonSoft.Json instead.

**If Above Doesn't Work**

One of the properties or descendant properties isn't serializable with the options above. If this is due to a parameterless constructor, then you'll need to create your own converter for deserialization. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

If one of the descendant property types if not serializable due to some other reason, you might be out of luck for a "simple" solution.

At this point, you're going to have to create a DTO for what you're attempting to send, and know how to build what you want on the other side from the data in the DTO.

Normally this isn't an issue unless properties are being used strangely (getter/setter use unsafe code, or have other "side effects"). I'm not familiar with the MS Office libraries, but I would not be surprised if some of the types in them that reference the document being worked on aren't serializable due to this reason.

**Conclusion**

Your questions implies you haven't tried serialization yet. You have to try, because you don't know what problems you're going to face until you do and it fails.

If you're lucky, the above code for JSON Serialization will just work. If it does, then your problem is solved. Use named pipes or memory mapped files or whatever, and load it on the other end.

If it doesn't just work, it's going to be complicated no matter what. Serialization is your only real option, and creating a DTO will be required if you're referencing MS Office library types that do some funky native/unsafe stuff.

You could of course get into unsafe code and direct memory manipulation yourself instead of serialization... but that is highly inadvisable and will almost certainly fail spectacularly.

Comment: Thank you. This is all my code so I can add anything needed to the classes. Thanks

Comment: What do you suggest for the IPC (always same machine) - named pipes?